# If $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are independent, $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ and $S_n\to S_\infty$ a.s., $\varphi_{S_\infty}(t)=\prod_{j=1}^\infty\varphi_{X_j}(t)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, characteristic-functions

**Problem:** Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be independent and let $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. Suppose that $S_n\to S_\infty$ almost surely. Then $S_\infty$ has characteristic function $\prod_{j=1}^\infty\varphi_{X_j}(t).$

**My Thoughts:** Since the random variables are independent, we have that
$$\varphi_{S_n}(t)=\prod_{j=1}^n\varphi_{X_j}(t).$$
That $S_n\to S_\infty$ almost surely implies that $S_n\to S_\infty$ in distribution as well, so that $\varphi_{S_n}(t)\to\varphi_{S_\infty}(t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$. But
$$\varphi_{S_\infty}(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_{S_n}(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{j=1}^n\varphi_{X_j}(t)=\prod_{j=1}^\infty\varphi_{X_j}(t),$$
so we are done.

---

I think this solution I have cooked up is too easy to be a problem in Rick Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples. Therefore, I would like to ask if anyone can spot any mistakes in the above argument.

Thank you for your time and feedback.

Comment: Relax, no mistakes here. The problem is easy and you have done it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by  Kavi Rama Murthy, your thoughts are correct; not all the problems in Durrett's book are hard, although a large part of them are tricky.